# json date returned from wcf service not consistent

Tags: javascript, .net, json, wcf

I have a service that returns a date. The weird thing is that most of the time it comes back like this: `/Date(1364227320000)/`

but sometimes it returns the date like this `/Date(1364050020139-0400)/`

when I open up the visual studio debugger, the dates look the same for each one (minus differences in time)

What could account for this difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the *kind* of the `DateTime` object (i.e., the value of its `Kind` property). If you're returning a `DateTime` with `DateTimeKind.Utc`, there will be no offset. If the date time is of kind `Local` or `Unspecified`, the offset will be written out.

You can find more information about the format in the "DateTime Wire Format" section of the ["Stand-Alone JSON Serialization" page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

This is handled in `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonWriterDelegator.WriteDateTimeInDefaultFormat()`. If the `DateTimeKind` is `Unspecified` or `Local`, it adds the UtcOffset to the end (the -400 part, meaning Utc - 4 hours).